# How to parse JSON data and eliminate duplicates in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I have a very large JSON file that I have downloaded from the web, and I need to parse this in Swift.  The JSON construction is an array of dictionaries.  Each dictionary object contains a key of "phone" (referring to the phone number), and whose value is the actual phone number in the form of a string.

What I would like to do, is iterate through the entire list of dictionary objects in the array, and ensure that there are no dictionary objects that have the same value for the key, "phone".  If a duplicate is found, I would like to eliminate it from the list, and print it out to the console.

Here is the relevant code that I have:

```
            guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String: Any]] else {
                print("error")
                return
            }

            for dict in json! {
                //This is where I would do the check

            }
```

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as

```
var ph = [String]()
var newjson = [[String:String]]()

    for dict in json {
        if ph.contains(dict["Phone"]!) {

            print("duplicate phone \(dict["Phone"]!)")

        } else {

        ph.append(dict["Phone"]!)
        newjson.append(dict)

        }
    }
    print(newjson)
```

Hare newjson is the new array of dictionary that do not have duplicate phone

Answer (score 1):

Use the array extension method to remove the duplicates from the json object

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    mutating func removeDuplicates() {
        var result = [Element]()
        for value in self {
            if !result.contains(value) {
                result.append(value)
            }
        }
        self = result
    }
}

    Alamofire.request(apiURL, method: .get, parameters:parameters, headers:headers)
                    .responseJSON { response  in
                            if let result = response.result.value {
                                let json = JSON(result)
                                var listArray = json["somekey"].arrayValue
                                listArray.removeDuplicates()
                                print(listArray)
                            }
                }
```